# Accordion view with multiple accordion panes in android

Tags: android, dynamic, accordion

I want to create an accordion view in which there are many sub accordion panes. The data binded in the accordion is dynamically coming from the web service. So whenever i make web service call the data will change accordingly. I know how to create a accordion view with static data but help me to do the same with dynamic data. I need to insert those accordion panes programmatically. Researched a lot on this before putting this question. Thanks in advance.

Below you can see the model of the view i require.![for example, When i press the data it should expand and another accordion pane should be displayed[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps4e0.png). This is my requirement. Here data is a dynamic data coming from web service

https://i.stack.imgur.com/55GqJ.png">

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically adding views into Accordion layout this might be helpful

https://jatin4rise.wordpress.com/2011/07/05/dynamic-accordion-creation-in-android/

Comment: I have already gone through this. This is not what i require. Anyway thanks